# Alternate between images on button click wpf

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

In my wpf project I have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onHTo.png)

I have an image with 2 buttons next to them, I would like to make it so that if I click one button, it changes the source of that image and if you click it again it goes to the next one, but if you click `button 2` it has the same **cycle** but in reverse. I have tried doing something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/image1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

But if I want to do it again I would have to do something like

```
if(image.Source == "/Resources/image1.png") {

code...
}
```

This doesn't work because it cannot convert the source into a string. How would I be able to do this? It is also very tedious to do if I have a lot of images, would there be a better way to make it? I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could have a set of BitmapImage class members like `private BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));` and use them like `if (image.Source == image1) { image.Source = image2; }`. Thus you would also avoid to re-create new BitmapImage objects on each change.

Comment: @Clemens I tried doing that but it won't work, the if statement will just return as false

Comment: It will of course only return true if you previously assigned `image.Source = image1;`

Comment: @Clemens you're right sorry, also another thing that I forgot to put in was the `return;` after the action, otherwise it would change it and then change it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done something like this

XAML looking like that :

```
<Window
x:Class="WPFAppTest.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFAppTest"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="800"
Height="450"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="ImageHolder" />
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            x:Name="Previous"
            Click="Previous_Click"
            Content="Previous" />
        <Button
            x:Name="Next"
            Click="Next_Click"
            Content="Next" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And for the code behind something like that :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<BitmapImage> bitmapImages { get; set; }
    private int Index { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bitmapImages = new List<BitmapImage>()
        {
           new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/1.png",UriKind.Relative)),
           new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/2.png",UriKind.Relative)),
           new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/3.png",UriKind.Relative)),
        };
        Index = 0;
        ImageHolder.Source = bitmapImages.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private void Previous_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Index = (Index - 1) == -1 ? bitmapImages.Count -1 : (Index - 1);
        ImageHolder.Source = bitmapImages[Index];
    }

    private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Index = (Index + 1) % bitmapImages.Count;
        ImageHolder.Source = bitmapImages[Index];
    }
}
```

With a List of BitmapImages Initialized in the constructor and an Index that hold the current displayed BitmapImage in the List.

Then you just have to make the index stay between 0 and the Count of BitmapImages in your list and you're done =)

PS: The images properties are set to Build Action : Content and Copy to Output Directory : Copy if Newer